# How to create circular images using Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

Is it possible to clip or apply a mask to an image using Prawn.

For example, I'm embedding an image into the PDF using `image http://path/to/image`. The image is square, but the PDF design requires a circle.

With HTML/ CSS I would apply a radius to the image to achieve this effect. Is there any way to do something similar with Prawn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on sunil-antony's answer, I came up with the following solution (using `save_graphics_state` to enclose drawing instructions, see Prawn documentation):

```
Prawn::Document.generate("x.pdf") do 
  image_width = 200
  image_x = 100
  image_y = 100 

  save_graphics_state do
    soft_mask do 
      fill_color 0,0,0,0 
      fill_circle [image_x + image_width/2, image_y - image_width/2], image_width/2
    end 

    image "example.jpg", at: [image_x, image_y], width: image_width, height: image_width
  end
end
```

Comment: image does not show up with save_graphics_state but without this block what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I did it with this code:

```
Prawn::Document.generate("x.pdf") do 
    width, height = 200, 200 

    soft_mask do 
        fill_color 0,0,0,0 
        fill_circle [100, bounds.top - 100], 100 
    end 

    image "example.jpg", :width => width, :height => height 
end
```

Comment: it helped but when I try to open my pdf file in browser some contents are disappeared on first page right after the image but if I open the pdf in pdf reader it become fine.